# UK Mobile Phone Validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm trying validate UK Mobile Phone Numbers, that are in the format:

`075xxxxxxxx` `077xxxxxxxx` `078xxxxxxxx` and `079xxxxxxxx`

Each number must either start with the above 3 numbers and be 11 digits in length.

I've looked around and found several regex's such as:

[RegEx1](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=331)
[RegEx2](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=308)

But nothing I'm struggling to match my exact needs.

Has anyone got an example that would work with the numbers I'm trying to validate?

Comment: Does the input of these numbers permit spaces, dashes, parentheses etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this regex `07[5789]\d{8}`

if you want to set dashes correct regex like this one `07[5789]\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}`

Answer (score 3):

`07[57-9]\d{8}`

1. `07` -> exact match
2. `[57-9]` -> matches 5, 7, 8 and 9
3. `\d{8}` -> 8 digits more

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$telno = "07712345678";

preg_match("^07[5789]{1}[0-9]{8}^",$telno,$matches);

if(count($matches) > 0 && $matches[0] == $telno){
    echo "valid tel no.";
}else{
    echo "invalid no.";
}

?>
```